# how to use one powershell result into other

Tags: powershell

I want to use the output of `Get-Cluster` into

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_computersystem -ComputerName [ClusterName] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

I'm new to powershell, can anyone help me how to replace `[ClusterName]` with example code

Comment: Please show us what you've tried in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's often useful to use helper variables instead of trying to create a one-liner. Start by saving the cluster object like so,

```
$c = Get-Cluster -name myCluster
```

Then you can examine the object. Query its properties and whatnot. When you know which member has desired data, access it with `$c.<property>` syntax like so,

```
gwmi win32_computersystem -computername $c.name | select -expand name
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner would be:

```
Get-Cluster | gwmi win32_computersystem -computername $_.Name | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```